# Flex 3: Collision detection and moving objects after collision

Tags: apache-flex, collision

I am creating a scheduling application that shows projects (wrapped within a canvas) on a 2 week calendar timeline.  If the user decides to move a project over by a day, i need to check and see if the moving project would then overlap with any other existing projects.  If it does, one of the two projects would need to move down the screen along the y axis until the two projects no longer overlap.

I've created a function that loops through a repeater item which is used to create the projects... the end result of this function is an arrayCollection that holds:

```
0. the id number within the repeater
1. the project title
2. x coordinate
3. y coordinate
4. the width of the project
5. the height of the project
```

I have also created a function that takes the two objects within the array collection and determines if they're overlapping.

I can not, however, figure out a working loop that goes through the array collection, compares each item within it, checks to see if they overlap, moves the project if they do overlap, and then continues onto the next project.

Also, I need to make sure that moving one project will not make it overlap with another.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

Figured it out... 
I ended up having to reset each elements y value to 0 each time any project is moved and then re-evaluating whether or not they collide.

Answer (score 1):

This is extremely hard to answer because of the nature of the project since every interaction and what you're trying to accomplish is different.

With that said, if it was me, I'd try to go a fully data driven approach. Have a 'project calendar' object that stores all the info it needs (mostly start and end timestamps since those are universal) and then place it in a data structure that would make sense, either an array or a doubly linked list of their order in the timeline.

From there it's a matter of limiting movement between the start and end time for the next (or previous) project on the data.  You'll need a custom component to be able to translate the timestamp into something representable to the user.

I've done something similar in the past, it wasn't an easy task to say the least.  Good luck.

Comment: I was thinking about running a for loop, comparing the current item to only items after it in the array collection, and moving items currently being looked at (the "i" object if you will)...